# DataTrigger on a specific Type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers

I have a scenario where I need to specify Functions like

```
void SomeFunction(int value)
```

For this I'm using two `DataGrid`s.

- The left `DataGrid` holds the Functions
- The right `DataGrid` holds the Parameters for the selected Function

I only want the Parameter `DataGrid` to be enabled when a valid Function is selected in the Function `DataGrid`. If the `NewItemPlaceHolder` *(the Last Row when `CanUserAddRows="True"` for a `DataGrid`)* is selected or if the selection is empty I want it to be disabled. I experimentet with a DataTrigger but I couldn't get it to work

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=functionDataGrid,
                                       Path=SelectedItem}"
                     Value="{x:Type systemData:DataRowView}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible to check if the value produced by the Binding is of a specific `Type`? Otherwise, does anyone have any other solutions to this? As of now, I'm handling this with the `SelectedCellsChanged` event but I would prefer not using code behind

Thanks

Comment: What is your new item placeholder?  How have you implemented that?

Comment: @Dan Puzey: It's the "empty" row before it is commited to the underlying Collection when `CanUserAddRows="True"` for `DataGrid`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If anyone else comes across the same problem, here's what I did to solve it. I created a `TypeOfConverter` that returns the `Type` of the value produced by the Binding.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=functionsDataGrid,
                               Path=SelectedItem,
                               Converter={StaticResource TypeOfConverter}}"
             Value="{x:Type data:DataRowView}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

**TypeOfConverter**

```
public class TypeOfConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null) ? null : value.GetType();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I try this I get a XamlParseException saying that I'm not specifying the Value of the DataTrigger ... any hint¿?

Comment: @SoMoS: In my example, data is defined as `xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"`. Have you included this?

Comment: I had a different type. Anyway I've changed the Converter to return the fullname of the type and used that at the Value. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered a DataTemplate for the right DataGrid (parameters)?

Then you could bind the DataContext of your right DataGrid to the SelectedItem of the left DataGrid.

And in your DataTemplate, you can make your right side look like an enabled DataGrid parameter entry form when the DataTemplate's DataType={x:Type local:FunctionObject}. When a 'FunctionObject' is not selected you can have a DataTemplate for that too which shows a disabled DataGrid parameter entry form, or you could choose to display nothing as well.